# Java for loop and class definition

Tags: java, class, loops, definition, mutators

Hey im very new at java so please bear with me :)

I have objects v1, v2, v3 with each one containing details of soccer players stats

```
     int LessThan25 = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < topscorer.size(); i++)
     {
         while (v**[i]**.getGoals() < 25)
         {
             LessThan25++;
         }
     }
```

My question is that how do I make this loop work? I want to be able to use the integers in the for loop for my while v loop which links to my class definition. (bolded part)

Appreciate the help :)

Comment: what is `topscorer` ?

Comment: @DonD Can you show more codes? For example, where you declare `topScorer` and `v`.

Comment: bad choice of [variable name](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: ArrayList<Player>topscorer = new ArrayList<Player>();
            
Player v1 = new Player(br.read(), br.readLine(), br.readLine(), br.readLine(), br.read(), br.readLine(), br.read(), br.readLine());
           
 topscorer.add(v1);

Comment: Yeah i know sorry it was just a rough version as i am only playing around with the features

Comment: What is this black magic: v**[i]**.  Can you clearly explain exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the i to be the number as i want it to refer back to my object (e.g v1, v2, v3 etc.)
I've tried putting just i there and it still wouldnt refer to the integer i in my for loop

Comment: See my example using Stream API, it's quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get what you mean now, you can do this to access **each** topScorer object:

```
for(int x=0; x<topScorer.size(); x++)    //iterate through all elements in topScorer
    if(topScorer.get(x).getGoals() < 25)
        lessThan25++;
```

The syntax to access the elements within an **ArrayList** is:

```
list.get(x) where x is the element you wanted to access (starts from 0)
```

---

## Alternatively:

Certainly, enhanced for-loop (**for each loop** works too):

```
for(Scorer s : topScorer)   //Scorer is the object type in your list
    if(s.getGoals() < 25)
        lessThan25++;
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you so much. Bless you buddy

Answer (score 0):

Use 'if' condition instead of 'while', i think that is what you looking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the enhanced `for` loop - a better idiom if using Java 5+.
Variable names should start lower case by convention.

```
    for(Player player : players) {
        if(player.getGoals < 25)
            lowerThan25Goals++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of **user3437460** is what you're looking for

```
 for(Scorer s : topScorer)
  if(s.getGoals() < 25)
    lessThan25++;
```

An example of a Player would have been nice,
sth. like

Player cRonaldo  = new Player(age, size, avgGoals, (total)goals);

Player lMessi = new Player(age, size, avgGoals, (total)goals);

Please, take a look at your while-loop

```
 while (topScorer[i].getGoals() < 25)
         {
             LessThan25++;
         }
```

This is an infinit loop. Becaue if u ever reach the point where a topScorer aka v **[i]** has less than '25' goals, u never get that loop to stop, and your counter **LessThan25** breaking the limit of your ALU ;)
*( lower case variables! )*

Could be a mistake, or missing code you provided. 
So just for you, being 'new' to Java, to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you can easily solve this problem using Stream API **in only one line** of code:

```
long lessThan25 = topScorer.stream()
                              .filter(element -> element.getGoals() < 25).count();
```

Moreover, using Streams the JVM can improve performance in background.